# "Read More" button position goes wrong when it is clicked.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, collapsable

I have implemented a collapsible div which expands on click "Read More" button. It's working fine. But by expanding button position goes wrong. I want button on the same position at which button is there on card when card is not expanded.

Here is my code

```css
 * {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

#myBtn {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;

  cursor: pointer;

  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  color: #7C5A0B;
}

/* .lbl-toggle::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;

  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);

  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
} */

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(250, 224, 66, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.Add {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 9px 0px #d8d7d7;
  border: 1px solid #eeee;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
}

.Text-box {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.Add-text {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}

.img {
  max-width: 88%;
  height: auto;
}

#conditional-tag {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div Class="box">
<p class="Add" id="conditional-tag">No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor </p>
<div class="inner-box">
  <img src="house.jpg" class="img">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="Text-box">
    <p class="Add" id="hideOnClick">No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor</p>
    <p class="text">2 Storey Terrace House</p>
    <p>Size &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : 1,860/1,302 sq.ft</p>
    <p>Tenure &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : Freehold</p>
    <p class="Add-text">RM37,8000</p>
    <span id="dots">...</span>
    <span id="more">
      <!--p style="font-weight: bolder;">No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor</p-->
      <p class="text">2 Storey Terrace House</p>
      <p>Size &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : 1,860/1,302 sq.ft</p>
      <p>Tenure &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : Freehold</p>
      <p class="Add-text">RM37,8000</p>
    </span>
  </p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more ></button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
      document.getElementById('hideOnClick').innerHTML = "Hello to the world";
      document.getElementById('conditional-tag').style.display = "block";
      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('hideOnClick').innerHTML = "No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor";
        document.getElementById('conditional-tag').style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less >";
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
  </script>
</div>
  </div>
```

I want button at the same position before and after card collapse. How can i get it?

Comment: I think main reason for this is your half-proper use of table display types. Your .inner-box and .wrapper have `display: table-cell`, but the parent is a normal block element, and even worse, the `p` element before them toggles between `none` and `block`, so it isn’t even a table cell or row. Build a proper table, in which the structure make sense - table, table row, table cells.

Comment: @misorude can you modify my code to work properly?

Comment: Set a static width to your div.wrapper, like `30%` or `250px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I removed `float: right` and I added `position:relative;` and set `right:250px;` .

```css
 * {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

#myBtn {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;

  cursor: pointer;

  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  color: #7C5A0B;
}

/* .lbl-toggle::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;

  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);

  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
} */

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(250, 224, 66, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.Add {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 9px 0px #d8d7d7;
  border: 1px solid #eeee;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
}

.Text-box {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.Add-text {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}

.img {
  max-width: 88%;
  height: auto;
}

#conditional-tag {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div Class="box">
<p class="Add" id="conditional-tag">No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor </p>
<div class="inner-box">
  <img src="house.jpg" class="img">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="Text-box">
    <p class="Add" id="hideOnClick">No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor</p>
    <p class="text">2 Storey Terrace House</p>
    <p>Size &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : 1,860/1,302 sq.ft</p>
    <p>Tenure &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : Freehold</p>
    <p class="Add-text">RM37,8000</p>
    <span id="dots">...</span>
    <span id="more">
      <!--p style="font-weight: bolder;">No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor</p-->
      <p class="text">2 Storey Terrace House</p>
      <p>Size &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : 1,860/1,302 sq.ft</p>
      <p>Tenure &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : Freehold</p>
      <p class="Add-text">RM37,8000</p>
    </span>
  </p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more ></button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
      document.getElementById('hideOnClick').innerHTML = "Hello to the world";
      document.getElementById('conditional-tag').style.display = "block";
      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('hideOnClick').innerHTML = "No. 60, Jalan Pendamar Indah 1B, Taman Pendamar Indah, Pelabuhan Klang, Selangor";
        document.getElementById('conditional-tag').style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less >";
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
  </script>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your divs with classes - inner-box and wrapper inside a container div and this will solve your problem. The problem currently is that your wrapper div is not taking 100% width because of which you see the 'Read Less' button not positioned properly.

```
<div>
    <div class="inner-box">
        <!-- your existing code here -->
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- your existing code here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for your reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/c1w8p7yj/